# MPMoviePlayerController doesn't play movie in full screen

Tags: mpmovieplayercontroller, fullscreen, ios6

I have a MPMoviePlayerController on my iPad app that works good when its frame is regular (not fullscreen).

When I tap the fullscreen button, the player goes fullscreen, but the movie stops. I perpetually see the title "Loading...", a black background, and the standard controls (back, play and next) disabled.

I declare an instance variable for the player:

```
MPMoviePlayerController *player;
```

In my implementation:

```
MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoUrl];

player.shouldAutoplay = NO;
player.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;
player.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded;
player.allowsAirPlay = YES;

player.view.frame = CGRectMake(xPos, yPos, width, height);

[self.view addSubview:player.view];

[player prepareToPlay];
```

Do you have any idea? I'm using iOS 6 SDK, and I'm testing the app on iPad 6.0 simulator and a real iPad2 with iOS 6 beta (latest).

Comment: Update: I installed the official iOS 6 on iPad2 and the problem is still there. So it is not due to the beta version of iOS 6.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

OMG!!!

I wrote...

```
[player stop];
```

in viewWillDisappear!!! How could I be so stupid?! No cake tonight...

Comment: You're not stupid. viewWillDisappear was not called in iOS 5. I've had problems after update to iOS 6 to... I made a register of what I found about this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12604827/1324647

Comment: That's not stupid, that was the smart thing to do prior to iOS6, since `MPMoviePlayerController` didn't create a VC over the top of your existing VC. Thanks for your Q+A, I've just spent an hour trying to diagnose the same problem!

Comment: Sigh. <raises hand in shame> Thanks for giving me back my afternoon!