# Entering full screen in MPMoviePlayerController calls viewWillDisappear and viewDidDisappear

Tags: mpmovieplayercontroller, ios6

To play video in my app, I set `MPMoviePlayerController` and add it to subview. The user can change to full screen mode using pinch gesture.

In this `viewController` (that contains the Movie Player View), I set the `viewWillDisappear` to set objects to nil.

But, in iOS 6, when activating fullscreen mode the `MPMoviePlayerController` in the view controller that contains the Movie Player View calls the methods `viewWillDisappear` and `viewDidDisappear`.

In iOS5, those methods were not called.

Comment: Look at this solution and see if it works for your problem. http://stackoverflow.com/a/15440274/1437106

Answer (score 16):

I came across this issue as well and it caused me a lot of headache. My temporary solution until the bug is fixed is to check the player's `fullscreen` Boolean value in `viewWillDisappear:` and/or `viewDidDisappear:`. If it returns `YES`, the movie is entering fullscreen mode and you should refrain from doing anything that might interrupt it.

Comment: The viewWillDisappear method is being called for all superviews as well. If you have a main controller that spawns another controller that contains the MPMoviePlayerController, when viewWillDisappear gets called, it goes all the way up the chain. Is there a workaround to interrupt the chain as well?

Comment: I guess you could try to skip the call to `[super viewWillDisappear:]` based on whether the `fullscreen` value is true or false. But based on your code that might cause more problems than it fixes.

Answer (score 3):

To everyone has noticed that and having problem with this, I found this report in community Open Radar: http://openradar.appspot.com/12327997

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this is a question but in case someone has a problem with the issue herein stated, that is, someone using a viewController (that contains the Movie Player View), I found the solution:

I was using a view controller with the Movie Player Controller and then presented this view controller as a subview. I just got rid of it and used the MoviePlayer.view as a subview directly and it works just fine.

Not a problem with iOS 5, but now, it is. Fix it and enjoy!